# very simple question about USB

Tags: persistence

I wish to install the newest Ubuntu 14+ on a 32 GB USB Stick.
I want to boot a fully operating ubuntu OS right but off the stick itself
How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Install Ubuntu , select the usb for your root partition and swap space.

Answer (score 0):

I use liveusb-creator for Fedora. Worked fine with all versions of Ubuntu since 10.04 to 14.04 (not official, these are the versions I've created live USBs for myself).

You can grab it from [here](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/).

Supports creating persistent storage as well.

[image]

Just click on Browse and select your Ubuntu ISO, and select USB as Target Device.
Linux version offered only command-line interface the last time i used it, though years ago, things might have changed since then.